# Breeze TempHire reference app -angular: JavaScript runtime error:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

when running the breeze tempHire reference app (angular) I am getting a javaScript runtime error 0x800a21138f Unable to get property 'canonicalUrl' of undefined or null reference when I click on any name in the resource management view.

If I ignore the error an continue, the app appears to work as expected, but I am in the process of learning breeze and angular so curious what this error is all about.

the error occurs in router.es5.js (which is part of angular I think) at what visual studio numbers as line 1453:

```
instruction.canonicalUrl += instruction.viewports[Object.keys(instruction.viewports)[0]].canonicalUrl;
```

Comment: Yes we are aware of this error. This particular sample is using a beta version of the new 'ngNewRouter'. The examples and documentation for composing the views are currently pretty basic. We are planning to revisit this issue once the Angular team has released an official version. FWIW, I see an open issue for this particular error. https://github.com/angular/router/issues/272. It may or may not be related.

Comment: Thanks good to know it is a known issue. If you could repost that as a proposed answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we are aware of this error. This particular sample is using a beta version of the new 'ngNewRouter'. The examples and documentation for composing the views are currently pretty basic. We are planning to revisit this issue once the Angular team has released an official version. FWIW, I see an open issue for this particular error. github.com/angular/router/issues/272. It may or may not be related.